# Order list of records by other created_at record column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

In my table:
Users can vote to battles records
Battle records has many votes records (votes by users with user_id in them)

I want to order the battles that the user voted to, by the created_at column of the vote record for each battle.

In english - I want to get list of the battles the user voted to by the time he voted to them.

My current code - the problem is this code return an array, I want to it with order:

```
scope :picked, -> (user_id) { where("battles.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(battle_id) FROM votes WHERE user_id = ?)", user_id)
                                    .sort_by { |b| b.votes.find_by(user_id: user_id ).created_at }.reverse }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to pass a block option when specifying the `has_many` association.
Assuming you have the following models:

```
Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :battle
end
```

And:

```
Battle < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

The user model should be something like this:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, -> { order(created_at: :desc) } # Ordering goes here
  has_many :battles, through: :votes
end
```

Then you'd query the battles directly:
`User.first.battles # Scoped by votes.created_at`

Comment: I don't want to return user battles, I want to return battles the user voted on...

Comment: @gal The associations I defined *will* only return the battles were voted on. Can you show the User/Vote/Battle model code so I can see what you're referring to?